# sending e-mails via sendmail using virtual-users

Tags: php, smtp, sendmail, email

Currently my sendmail send e-mail with following header:

```
Received: (from www-data@localhost)
```

I want this header to be like:

```
Received: (from contact@mydomain)
```

but I am also hosting multiple domains on my server, so I would like to be able to do this for multiple domains.
I have read about http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/tips/virtual_hosting/

How can I use this to SEND e-mails with multiple domain names? Where can I set this?

Answer (score 0):

When you call the sendmail command in your code, specify the SMTP FROM address like this:

`sendmail -f "contact@mydomain.com"`